# Direct proof for the chi-square value being chi-square distributed with one degree of freedom for a 2x2 contingency table

Tags: probability-theory

for a 2x2 contingency table, we have for the observed and expected frequencies the following:
[image: Contingency table]

We require e.g. that
[image: row and column check sum]
which are that the row and column sums have to match between observed and expected frequencies where for the expected frequencies are calculated as e.g. here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Testing_for_statistical_independence.
With the three equations, we can calculate the forth one. Further more, with these three equations, we can transform the chi-square sum as follows
[image: chi-square sum]
by making a common denominator and using the identities for differences between the observed and expected frequencies from the requirement.
The term
[image]
is clearly chi-square distributed with one degree of freedom by definition. However, what is the argument why the factor in front of it
[image]
does not change the distribution for the total equation?

Is there a change to see that it converges against 1 at least for large expected frequencies or is there a more abstract argument why in spite of that (scaling) factor the second equation in the chi-square calculation is still chi-square distributed with one degree of freedom?

I find only very abstract proofs of the degrees of freedom for a test of independence with a chi-square test in textbooks. So I thought a direct calculation might help to understand this issue of degrees of freedom better.
However, I cannot make the last conclusion in this example. So I am very happy for your help.

Thank you

Tim

Answer (score 1):

Let us begin with the definitions:

$$
E_{1}:=(O_{1}+O_{3})\frac{O_{1}+O_{2}}{N},\ E_{2}:=(O_{2}+O_{4})\frac{O_{1}+O_{2}}{N},\ E_{3}:=(O_{1}+O_{3})\frac{O_{3}+O_{4}}{N},\ E_{4}:=(O_{2}+O_{4})\frac{O_{3}+O_{4}}{N}
$$

With the requirement

$$
O_{1}+O_{2}+O_{3}+O_{4}=N
$$

we can conclude:

$$
E_{1}+E_{2}=O_{1}+O_{2},\ E_{3}+E_{4}=O_{3}+O_{4},\ E_{1}+E_{3}=O_{1}+O_{3},\ E_{2}+E_{4}=O_{2}+O_{4}
$$

From this, it follows:

$$
E_{2}-O_{2}=O_{1}-E_{1},\ E_{3}-O_{3}=O_{1}-E_{1},\ E_{4}-O_{4}=O_{2}-E_{2}=E_{1}-O_{1}
$$

with which we can calculate:

$$
\begin{split}\chi^{2} & =\sum_{i=1}^{4}\frac{(O_{i}-E_{i})^{2}}{E_{i}}\\
 & =\frac{(O_{1}-E_{1})^{2}}{E_{1}}+\frac{(O_{1}-E_{1})^{2}}{E_{2}}+\frac{(O_{1}-E_{1})^{2}}{E_{3}}+\frac{(O_{1}-E_{1})^{2}}{E_{4}}\\
 & =\left(1+\frac{E_{1}}{E_{2}}+\frac{E_{1}}{E_{3}}+\frac{E_{1}}{E_{4}}\right)\frac{(O_{1}-E_{1})^{2}}{E_{1}}\\
 & =\left(\frac{E_{2}E_{3}E_{4}+E_{1}E_{3}E_{4}+E_{1}E_{2}E_{4}+E_{1}E_{2}E_{3}}{E_{2}E_{3}E_{4}}\right)\frac{(O_{1}-E_{1})^{2}}{E_{1}}
\end{split}
$$

Let us assume that the $E_i, i\in{1,2,3,4}$ are large enough such that $\frac{(O_{i}-E_{i})^{2}}{E_{i}},i\in\left\{ 1,2,3,4\right\}$ are normally distributed.
Is there a way to see or to rewrite some of the equation such that we see that the right hand side is chi-square distributed with one degree of freedom?
If yes, we could generalize this calculation to a direct proof of the degrees of freedom for the chi-square test of independence.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the values $E_i$ for $i \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ are not random variables.  Only the observed quantities $O_i$ are random variables.  The $E_i$ relate to what we *expect* the frequency counts to be for a given sample size $n$.  For an experiment with a predetermined number of observations, they will not change from experiment to experiment, whereas the $O_i$, the observed cell frequencies, may change due to the randomness inherent in the sampling process.

Consequently, the distributional properties of the statistic $\chi^2$ do not depend on any constant factors with respect to the $O_i$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I struggle a bit with the answer. My problem is, e.g. that for $c \frac{(O_1 - E_1)^2}{E_1}$, c>1, the corresponding chi-square value is interpreted as less unlikely as it is scaled by c to a bigger value that is more unlikely for the corresponding term with c=1. In other words we scale the test statistic.
Analogously, if we scale a normally distributed random variable with mean=0 and variance=1, the variance will scale as well.
So, having this in mind, where is the difference to the above described situation? Do I think wrongly here? Where do I miss a thing?

Answer (score 0):

(It's not clear how to obtain the equation you quoted involving denominator $E_2E_3E_4$; is there a source for this result?)

In a $2\times 2$ contingency table the test statistic
$\sum_{i=1}^4\frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}$ has *approximately* a chi-square distribution with one degree of freedom.  Here is a derivation, using slightly different notation. The derivation is all algebra.

Suppose you have split a population of $N$ individuals into two groups, and counted the number of "positives" vs "negatives" among the two groups, obtaining a $2\times 2$ contingency table:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&\text{Group 1}&\text{Group 2}\\
\hline
\text{Positive}&a & b\\
\text{Negative}&c & d\\
\hline
&n_1:=a+c&n_2:=b+d&N:=n_1+n_2\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
Start with [the identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1704169/215011)
$$\sum_{i=1}^4\frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}=\frac{N(ad-bc)^2}{(a+b)(c+d)(a+c)(b+d)}.
$$
Now let $p_1:=\frac a{n_1}$ be the observed proportion of positives in group 1, and let $p_2:=\frac b{n_2}$ be the observed proportion of positives in group 2, and define $q_1$ and $q_2$ similarly to be the observed proportions of negatives. We can express the cell counts in terms of these new variables:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&\text{Group 1}&\text{Group 2}\\
\hline
\text{Positive}&a=n_1p_1 & b=n_2p_2\\
\text{Negative}&c=n_1q_1 & d=n_2q_2\\
\hline
&n_1&n_2&N\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
Substitute these values into the identity and simplify:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^4\frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}&=\frac{N(n_1p_1n_2q_2-n_2p_2n_1q_1)^2}{(n_1p_1+n_2p_2)(n_1q_1+n_2q_2)(n_1)(n_2)}\\
&=\frac{Nn_1n_2(p_1 q_2-p_2q_1)^2}{(n_1p_1+n_2p_2)(n_1+n_2-(n_1p_1+n_2p_2))}
\end{aligned}
$$
Writing $N=n_1+n_2$, and noting that that $p_1q_2-p_2q_1=p_1(1-p_2)-p_2(1-p_1)=p_1-p_2$, and defining $p:=(n_1p_1+n_2p_2)/(n_1+n_2)$ (**the pooled estimate of the proportion of positives**), this equals
$$\frac{(n_1+n_2)n_1n_2(p_1-p_2)^2}{(n_1+n_2)p(n_1+n_2)(1-p)}=\left(\frac{p_1-p_2}{\sqrt{p(1-p)\left(\frac1{n_1}+\frac1{n_2}\right)}}\right)^2
$$
which is the square of the $z$ **test statistic for comparing two proportions**. The $z$ test statistic has approximately standard normal distribution, hence its square has approximately chi-square distribution with one degree of freedom. (By definition, $\chi^2$ is the distribution of the square of a standard normal variable.)

---

**Added:** In what sense is the $z$ distribution approximately standard normal? The $z$ statistic converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$ as $n_1$ and $n_2$ tend to infinity -- under the null hypothesis that the population frequencies are equal for group 1 and group 2. This fact follows from the Central Limit Theorem and Slutsky's theorem. The argument is similar to that for the [single-sample test of proportions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1859869/215011). Note that the $p_1$ and $p_2$ named above are the *sample* proportions, i.e., observed from the data; they are not the population proportions.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the detailed answer. However, I think this idea will not work for an nxm contingency table. So please let me provide a detailed calculation of the one above with a clear definition in particular of ,∈1,2,3,4. The idea of this post would also be to be able to have an idea that scales for an arbitrary nxm table. Let me post a rigorous calculation below. 
Please let me know if know the calculation of the initial post is clear.

Comment: Regarding the z test statistic: We need that the term is N(0,1) distributed. I do not see why p_1-p_2 are supposed to be zero under the hypothesis that the two features are independent of each other or the observed frequencies match the expected ones. However, in my understanding this would be required, right?

Comment: @Tim Please see my edit. Note that the distribution of the test statistic is never exactly chi-square. The proof of chi-square distribution is an "asymptotic" result, as the sample sizes tend to infinity. You are right that the argument for a $2\times 2$ table is a special case and I don't think it can extended to larger tables. For arbitrary $r\times c$ tables the proof is quite advanced. Since the results are asymptotic, it's not likely that $(r-1)\times(c-1)$ degrees of freedom can arise from elementary arguments, so justifications for the degrees of freedom tend to be 'hand-waving'.

Comment: @Tim Your derivation of the equation with denominator $E_2E_3E_4$ is very clear, thanks. I should have seen that myself.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the further comments.
Regarding the asymptotic behavior of the test statistic. 
I thought that for increasing number of data points (N), the terms $$\frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}$$ asymptotically converge to a normal distribution N(0,1). However, the number of degrees of freedom is not asymptotic but fixed. I do not know details of proofs but are these two issues decoupled?

Do you know some (new) literature where a proof for a rxc table is (didactically) done in a nice way?

Thanks a lot again

Comment: @Tim My calculations find that, given the above assumptions, the $i=1$ contribution $\frac{(O_1-E_1)^2}{E_1}$ behaves like $\frac{n_2q}N  Z^2$, so its asymptotic limit is not $N(0,1)$, and the scaling factor (the expression with denominator $E_2E_3E_4$) behaves like $\frac N{n_2q}$, so in the end we do recover $Z^2$, but not in the way you intended. So your direct calculation for demonstrating chi-square with one d.f. is unfortunately not as straightforward as it seems. To answer your last question, the only rigorous proof of degrees of freedom that I know is the abstract, difficult one.

Comment: Can please you provide one/some textbooks where you find the explanation well done?
What is the mathematical area/subject where you usually find the chi-square theory? I mean even in books about probability theory the chi-square discussion  does not to be standard.